# Display Image using html in JLabel

Tags: java, html, jlabel

I used the following way to convert an ImageIcon into a thumbnail :

```
ImageIcon im = new ImageIcon(url);
Image image = im.getImage().getScaledInstance(80,100,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
```

Now I'm having problems when I try to display the Image in JLabel using html. Before converting the ImageIcon into Image, the following code was working fine:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>" + im);
```

But now when I try to do the same using the Image, it doesn't work. Any idea of how to display the resulting Image using html in a JLabel?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><img height='" + height + "' width='" + width
               + "' src='" + url + "'></html>");
```

For example:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><img  height='80' width='100' src='https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/mdn-logo-sm.png' /></html>");
```

Note: Don't add px to the height or width values

Some documentation here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/ImageView.html

Comment: This is a simple, yet effective way to add images, though I understand it is internet dependent! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

You cannot display HTML code inside a JLabel. You are going to need to use an htmlPanel. You can set the perferred size of it later, here is what you need to add.

```
JPanel htmlPanel = new HtmlPanel("<html><body><img src="file path goes here"></body></html>");
```

Here is the complete code I whipped up.

```
JPanel htmlPanel = new HtmlPanel("<html><body><img src="images/file.png"></body></html>");

htmlPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(TheWidthGoesHere, TheHeightGoesHere));
```

Then you can just add the htmlPanel to your frame like you would with any other component.

```
frame.add(htmlPanel);
```

Comment: What I want is to display Image image using HTML in a JLabel. HTML can be used in JLabels, I'm using it and it works fine with ImageIcon but I'm failing to use it to display Image image.

Comment: I am not %100 sure you can display an image with HTML in a JLable. I don't know what your using this for but there must be a work around.